# how to hide TabBar when keyboard is open in expo react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Currently, the TabBarBottom is placed above the keyboard for few seconds and after that it goes down.
i want to completely hide the TabBar when keyboard is open.

```
   expo sdk :- 38
    react-navigation": “^4.0.9”,
    “react-navigation-tabs”: “^2.9.0”,
    "Plaform: "Android"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
  }}
>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanatory text! Although the answer might be helpful as it stands, it's often even more helpful to be able to read an explanation of the code and why it works.

Comment: Note typo screenOpitons should be screenOptions - cannot edit 

Comment: @Sebastian it makes the tab bar hide on keyboard... what other explanation is needed...?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean @RiskitAll

Answer (score 4):

Since tabBarOptions is deprecated you can try `tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true` in screenOptions

Comment: Note, this is true if you are using `react-navigation` 6.x+

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `keyboardHidesTabBar: true` in tabBarOptions.

Comment: in react-navigation-4 keyboardHidesTabBar: true is bydefault true and i also try inside tabBarOptions but it didnot work

Comment: have you tried what is the behavior if you keyboardHidesTabBar:`false`. It's wried but in the app i'm working in this is set to `false` and the keyboard hides the tab.

Comment: i resolved this issue after adding "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan", inside app.json.
i am using expo sdk-38. and in expo sdk-38 if we want to hide tabbar then we manually set "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan", inside app.json

More details canbe found here:-
https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-5aa0

Answer (score 1):

PREBA ESTO

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    keyboardHidesTabBar: true //<=====
  }}
>
```